# Integral of a function over a surface of revolution

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f=x \mapsto f(x)$ and $M \subset [a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^2$ be a surface of revolution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) around the $x$ axis. We want to calculate
\begin{equation}
\label{equation1}
\int_M f(x) ds.
\end{equation}

Ok let's assume we know the parametrized distance $m(x)$ of the set $M$ from the $x$ axis. Then the surface area of $M$ would be (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution):
$$
2 \pi \int_a^b  x \sqrt{1+m'(x)^2}dx.
$$
As the $f$ depends only on $x$, my hypothesis is that our integral over $M$ is simply
$$
2 \pi \int_a^b f(x) x \sqrt{1+m'(x)^2}dx.
$$

Is this right? Why? Why not? What are the assumptions on $f$?

Comment: What does the notation $\int_Mf(x)d(x,y,z)$ mean?  Specifically, what is $d(x,y,z)$?  I believe you have not copied the problem statement correctly, which will put a wrench in anyone finding the correct answer.

Comment: That looks right to me.  You're just integrating a function on the surface of the revolution.  If $f(x) = 1$ you get the surface area.

Comment: @IanJ Did you notice that $f$ is a complex-valued function?

Comment: Ben W: d(x,y,z) is an infinitesimal surface element on M, could be denoted as ds too, I changed it

Comment: @BenW I did notice that $f(x)$ could be complex, but in this case it appears that the real and imaginary parts are linearly independent.  There is no interaction with $ds$ except the product.  I don't think this has any particular physical interpretation though.

Comment: Im integrating a function over a spherical cap -- that is the physical relevance in my case

Comment: I can use this result in my engineering paper without proofs, but I would still like to know how to justify this mathematically.